# white spaces in visual composer rows

Tags: html, wordpress, css, visual-composer

i have a weird issue with visual composer rows in my wordpress theme.

block are set on full width but in RTL version VC rows display white spaces around right and left.

can you help me to fix this?
i've tried to edit margins and paddings but can't fix it.

thanks.

Comment: In the line `<div class="wpb_column col-md-12">` you may just remove substring `col-md-12` to reach what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Create a useful class on your style.css. Now go to your page section. View the page with html view or raw code find `div class section-focus bg-dark` and before this you have another `div class wpb_column col-md-12`.

```
.nopadding{
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
}
```

Add this nopadding class like this

```
<div class="wpb_column col-md-12 nopadding"><!-- Here you need to add that no padding class-->
<div class="section-focus bg-dark">
```

if you add this correctly the you will get No white space around.  [image: This]
If it doesn't work then try with !important like [if you have custom css file then you don't need to use !important]

```
.nopadding{
 padding-left: 0 !important;
 padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS you should as described above use something like the following.

```
.no-padding-margin {
     padding-left: 0;
     padding-right: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
}
```

Visual Composer, row settings

[image: Visual Composer, row settings]

The .no-padding-margin class should be added in your VC row. Above i've included an image which is part of the ROW settings.

Visual Composer, add class to row settings

[image: Visual Composer, add class to row settings]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14151197)

Comment: I understand your reaction, due to my reputation I wasn't able to respond to the guy that provided the no padding solution.